# Как найти музыкальный трек с басами, похожими на образец?

Tags: аудио, распознавание, анализ, музыка

Возможно ли распознать звук?

Пример: допустим есть трек в стиле EDM (Electronic Dance Music), и мне очень понравилось звучание баса в этом треке. Нужно программным путем вытащить бас, а затем распознавать его в других треках.

Знаю, вопрос не очень корректный, но думаю, мысль я передал. Любые наводки, ссылки, литература, будет горячо приветствоваться.

Comment: Копайте в сторону обработки сигналов. Насколько я помню, можно использовать Преоброзование Фурье и на основании гормоник уже искать. Впрочем я могу и ошибаться. В этом я не спец.